# why Vue compute don't call get after setting dependent value in set function?

Tags: vue.js, get, set, computed-properties

I define a computed value as bellow

template :

```
         <date-picker
            v-model="rangeDate"
            type="date"
            format="jYYYY/jMM/jDD"
            display-format="jYYYY/jMM/jDD"
            input-class="vgt-input"
            :state="errors.length > 0 ? false : null"
            :placeholder="$t('fields.ads.rangeDate')"
            clearable
            range
          />
```

{{rangeDate}}

script:

```
data: () => ({
    body: {}
  ),


computed: {
rangeDate: {
      get() {
        return [this.body.sdate, this.body.fdate]
      },
      set(newVal) {
        // console.log(newVal)
        if (newVal.length === 0) {
          this.body.sdate = ''
          this.body.fdate = ''
        } else if (newVal.length === 1) {
          this.body.sdate = newVal[0]
          this.body.fdate = `${newVal[0]}`
        } else {
          this.body.sdate = newVal[0]
          this.body.fdate = `${newVal[1]}`
        }
      },
    },
},
```

this value is used for range calendar but by setting that through v-model it set the sdate and fdate correctly but in other places of template that show rangeDate won't change.

I thought the computed value must be recalculated after the change of each depended values but when the dependent values change in set function don't cause to call get function.
please help me.

Comment: The question lacks Vue version. Is it Vue 2? Then there's a problem with reactivity

Answer (score 0):

I understood that changing the value of an object does not affect raising the watch method.